# Disable Categories with no Products Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am looking to disable any categories with no products assigned and have no idea where to begin? I can run mysql queries or run from SSH. I just don't know what to enter exactly.

I have over 800 categories in my setup and it takes the homepage 25 seconds to load. I wanted to try turning off unnecessary categories to see if it speeds it up.

Comment: Are you loading categories in home page? Better if you share the URL of home page